# R HTTR Webpage Scraping, need to click button for additional data

Tags: r, web-scraping, httr

I'm trying to pull in the HTML content of the following webpage, but I am only able to pull in the first 25 results. 
https://untappd.com/search?q=Oktoberfest

There's a "Show More" button that expands the search to list the next 25. Essentially, i'm trying to print the name of every beer that appears on this list (not just the first 25) with the following code:

```
require(httr)

for(i in 1:25){
Search.Term <- "Oktoberfest Beer"
Search.Term <- gsub(" ","+",Search.Term)
url.name <- paste0("https://untappd.com/search?q=",Search.Term)
url.get <- GET(url.name)
url.content <- content(url.get,as="text")


Start.String <- as.numeric(data.frame(gregexpr("beer-details",url.content[[1]])[1])[i,1])
new.test <- substr(url.content,Start.String,Start.String+500)
Start.String <- as.numeric(data.frame(gregexpr("[0-9]",new.test))[1,1])
new.test <- substr(new.test,Start.String,Start.String+100)
Start.String <- as.numeric(data.frame(gregexpr(">",new.test)[1])[1,1])
End.String <- as.numeric(data.frame(gregexpr("<",new.test)[1])[1,1])
Beer.Name <- substr(new.test,Start.String+1,End.String-1)

print(Beer.Name)
}

[1] "Samuel Adams OctoberFest"
[1] "Spaten Oktoberfest Ur-Märzen / Winter"
#etc...
```

Is there a way that I can write the first section of the code so that the "show more" button expands? I'll admit that i'm fairly new to web scraping, so any help is much appreciated. Is there a way with the rvest package where this works?

I know that with the javascript buttons, there is typically a way to do this. I just don't know how.

Thanks!

Comment: No no no no, don't use regex to parse HTML; use an HTML parsing package like [rvest](https://github.com/hadley/rvest). You can try to follow the link with `rvest::follow_link`, but that just takes me to a login page, which will take a bit of work with a form. In the not-unlikely chance that something needs to happen in JavaScript, you'll need to move to RSelenium, which is much more powerful, but more work. Check site terms, too, of course. tl;dr: This is not a simple site to scrape.

Comment: So, you know they have an [API](https://untappd.com/api), right?

Comment: Yes. The API takes a few weeks to process, so I'm just using HTTR and gregexpr. It's not the difficult to parse the HTML once the pattern is recognized. Once the loop is in place, I can extract what I need in no time. As I stated above, my only issue is that I can't access the whole list past 25 records because of the button.